# Is there any way i can check that a messags has been published?

Tags: java, rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I need to check for messages inside a RabbitMQ queue using Java. I have gone through [the standard Java API documentation of RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/api-guide.html)  but it seems that there is no standard way described there. I have also referred [to this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/2.1.7.RELEASE/api/) but failed to find any standard way.

What I am trying to achieve by this can be summarised as:

1. My application will publish a message into a `fanout`  exchange.
2. Now here I want to get the contents of the message that has been published by my application or a confirmation whether the message is published or not into the correct exchange.

How can this be done using Java?

Comment: Why not check the message before publishing it?

Comment: Did you check about the `publisher confirms` concept in `RabbitMQ`?

Comment: Check out https://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use publisher confirms, add the message itself to the `CorrelationData` argument then, when you get a callback with the Ack, you can access the message.

See [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/html/#template-confirms).